# Yodlee get_accounts sometimes returns zero result / empty response

Tags: yodlee

Here is the scenario:

1. User logins to the bank successfully (via Fastlink)
2. Right after user logs in, I get user's provider_accounts (via /providerAccounts API)
3. Then when I call to get the accounts, (via /accounts) I sometimes get empty response (zero accounts found?)

When I try later (seconds or minutes after) I get some accounts information back.

Is this because Yodlee is still trying to gather account information when I'm making `/accounts` api call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the accounts are still being added/linked.

Using the `requestId` and `providerAccountId` provided by FastLink callback, you need to poll continuously to know the **refresh status** of the account linking process and once it's done, you can call the get accounts.

Read more about the refresh status in the "[Add/Update Account Process Status](https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/docs/v1_1/Migrating_To_Yodlee_API_1_1#Legacy_API_Vs_Yodlee_API)" section.

Yodlee makes things easier now with webhooks. Read more here:
[Using Webhooks with the Yodlee Core API](https://developer.yodlee.com/KnowledgeBase/Using-Webhooks_with_Envestnet-Yodlee-API)

TL/DR: You need to wait for the add/link completion before retrieving the accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the response

Comment: One more follow up question; I am currently using Fastlink 2.0. Does 2.0 support `requiestId` and `providerAccountId` on callbacks?

Comment: @chrishyunhokim No Fastlink 2.0 doesn't support that. BTW, for any specific reason, you are using Fastlink 2.0? I'd recommend using v1.1 APIs with Fastlink 3.0